# Does stunnel cache DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, stunnel

I'm using stunnel in client mode to proxy between my Haproxy and a HTTPS backend server. I've read that Haproxy caches the resolved IPs on each config load, which isn't a problem in my current setup. However, it got me thinking whether or not stunnel caches the DNS results as well. I find that there's a `delay = yes` option which sounds like it should alleviate my concern. From the manual:

> **delay = yes | no**
>
> > delay DNS lookup for connect option
> >
> > This option is useful for dynamic DNS, or when DNS is not available
> >     during stunnel startup (road warrior VPN, dial-up configurations).
> >
> > Delayed resolver mode is automatically engaged when stunnel fails to
> >     resolve on startup any of the connect targets for a service.
> >
> > Delayed resolver inflicts failover = prio.
> >
> > default: no

If I set `delay = yes`, will the DNS be resolved at every single connection, or does it use the OS's DNS cache (which would invalidate)?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** It doesn't cache the IP addresses

Asked this in the stunnel mail list, the author and maintainer Michal kindly responded to the question:

> I specifically introduced the "delay" option to deal with dynamic IP
>   addresses.  Stunnel does not attempt to cache the IP addresses with
>   "delay = yes".  The local library may cache them, but it should honor
>   the TTL.